# Android can't get token to change soft keyboard

Tags: android, ime

I have a custom keyboard, where I have a button to change IME....

From the Android sample code, I've found the following:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.switchToNextInputMethod(getToken(), false /* onlyCurrentIme */);
```

But I'm just getting `can't resolve 'getToken()'`... I'm doing this from a class that extends `InputMethodService`... What's the correct approach to getting the token from inside a keyboard then?

If not the above, then this one could work as well:

```
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
imeManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(/*token?*/, 0);
```

My class:

```
public class CustomKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    public final static int CodeRowFourGlobe = 55041;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.custom_keyboard);
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    public void closeKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imeManager.switchToNextInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), false /* onlyCurrentIme */);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE) {
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        } else if (primaryCode == CodeRowFourGlobe) {
            InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imeManager != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Close keyboard");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_keyboard_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(kv.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
imm.switchToNextInputMethod(kv.getApplicationWindowToken(), false);
imm.switchToNextInputMethod(kv.getWindowToken(), false /* onlyCurrentIme */);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(kv.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trick for me was to use the following:

```
private IBinder getToken() {
    final Dialog dialog = getWindow();
    if (dialog == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return window.getAttributes().token;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
IBinder token = getWindow().getWindow().getAttributes().token;
```

Can be used anywhere inside an `InputMethodService`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
public void fun(View view) {
       InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imeManager.switchToNextInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), false /* onlyCurrentIme */);
}
```

Comment: Okay, but since it's being called from a keyboard and not from a view, which view do I then use to close it with? Using the KeyboardView doesn't seem to have an effect

Comment: `closeKeyboard(kv);` (kv being my KeyboardView and closeKeyboard instead of fun from your code)

Comment: You need to pass the current view.

Comment: But that was my question... I'm calling it from a KeyboardView, not from inside an app... So how do I get the correct, active view?

Comment: Then take the activities current focus and try?

Comment: I've updated my question with some more code :/ haven't been able to get it to work yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96146/discussion-between-nigam-patro-and-user969043).